# How to trigger quick suggestions without IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to turn on quick-suggestions/auto-complete for words in a file that isn't supported by IntelliSense? For instance in Sublime the quick suggest box will suggest matching words in the file which usually ends up pretty useful.

If I manually trigger the suggestion box the suggestions I would want to have automatically show up while typing do show up. Just trying to make them show up without me hitting ctrl+space constantly.

editor.quickSuggestions is already true and I've played around with the delay. Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode doesn't have a setting to enable 24x7 suggestions for [basic languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editingevolved#_intellisense). As a workaround, you can try adding many keyindings in the following shape:

Go to `AppMenu | File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` and in your `keybindings.json` file use:

```
[
{ "key": "a", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "b", "command": "^editor.action.triggerSuggest", "when": "editorTextFocus" }
...
]
```

I know it's ugly, but this is the only workaround I can think of until such a setting is added.

Answer (score 0):

I came here while looking for a solution for enabling tailwind intellisense in combination with react. Eventually I found a post pointing to the settings `editor.quicksugestions`. I turned on "strings" like in the below example, which made intellisense automatically popup inside string tags.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": true
}
```