# Autocomplete without ctrl+space

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I must use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for get complete variants. But I need it often. I need list of variants every time when I press a key. How I can setup it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic text/word suggestions are controlled by [`"editor.quickSuggestions"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings)  which is enabled by default.

[image]

This will provide basic word suggestions while typing based on other words found in the current document, but does not get activated in all cases, such as when editing within a word. See this answer for a suggested workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30007192/306149

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks.