# How to fix flutter's AutoComplete widget not being recommended in vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

in VS code
For example, I wrap with widget in flutter's widget.
Next, I try to convert what is written as a widget into a GestureDetector.
When I type 'Ges', the widgets should be recommended with AutoComplete, but it doesn't work.
Please let me know how I can fix this.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to trigger autocomplete manually? By default it is `CTRL+SPACE`

Comment: I also know that AutoComplete goes manually. It used to be automatic, but it didn't work.

Comment: So triggering it manually works but you want it to automatically come up, right?

Comment: You're right It works manually now, but I want it to appear automatically. It's too annoying.

Comment: Yeah the trigger for autocomplete sometimes works strange, i find it that it helps to introduce space between what you type and the rest of line. Similar problem was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839733/autocomplete-without-ctrlspace)